# What's the purpose of index of mongoose.schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've read '[mongoose-express-session](https://github.com/steveukx/mongoose-express-session/blob/master/lib/MongooseStore.js#L21-L39)' and i found the index of the Shema.

I've thought i should use index like this

```
  var animalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
  });

  animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

but, why like this?

```
 index:{
         expires: options.sessionLifespan || MongooseStore.defaultOptions.sessionLifespan
       }
```

code snippet

```
 MongooseStore.defaultOptions = {
        connection: 'mongodb://localhost/connect-sessions',
        sessionLifespan: 60 * 20,
        modelName: 'Session',
        superclass: require('events').EventEmitter
};

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        var Session = new Schema({
            expiry: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now,
                index: {
                    expires: options.sessionLifespan || MongooseStore.defaultOptions.sessionLifespan
                }
            }
        });
```

You can see original code here : https://github.com/steveukx/mongoose-express-session/blob/80ebad12be335515d9698cdd6c08c5808da7e577/lib/MongooseStore.js#L21-L39

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @deceze i found it!
It was index-ttl.
Finally I could fix my issue that session deletes in 20 min